# Is there anyway to send and receive email in linux command using POP3?

Tags: linux, email

New to `mail` in linux command line, I don't know it support POP3 protocal or not which icloud mail service using?

Is there a more handy command line mail clinet than `mail`?

Comment: @technomage Yes I think so. How can I move the question to `superuser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to send and receive email in linux command using POP3?

No, by definition. POP can only be used to receive mail -- it has no provisions for sending mail. Mail is typically sent using SMTP. (Which `mail` can do, indirectly, by way of `sendmail`.)

Standard implementations of `mail` can only read local mail (e.g, mail messages stored in a mbox file or maildir). You will need to use a program such as [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) to copy mail from a POP server to your local machine, or use a different mail client.

> Is there a more handy command line mail clinet than mail?

Yes. `mail` is the oldest commonly available command-line mail client, and as such is probably the least convenient possible one to use; there are a lot of far superior mail programs, including alpine, mutt, mh, gnus, and many others.

Comment: I've checked out the manual of the GNU Mailutils http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html it seems to support POP3 which as you said for receiving mail only.

Comment: That's describing the entirety of the Mailutils suite. GNU `mail` itself doesn't support POP (it only reads mail spools and maildirs), but some of the other utilities, such as `movemail` (similar to `fetchmail`) do support POP.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `pine`, `elm` or `mutt`

pine - http://www.washington.edu/pine/

elm - http://www.instinct.org/elm/

mutt - http://www.mutt.org/